# monitor directory and log the file opening time based on the file open event

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I want to create a cpp - MFC application to log the file opened time in the specified directory. I've tried with the **`ReadDirectoryChangesW`** and I can log the file operation details but does not provide the file opening event. is there is an alternative method to find the opening time and event of a file?

Comment: Maybe [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/950/CDirectoryChangeWatcher-ReadDirectoryChangesW-) helps.

Comment: @MichaelWalz it won't give the details of the file open. It gives change details like update, remove, create, etc

Comment: This could be done by writing a [filesystem mini filter driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/file-system-minifilter-drivers), but it propably is a complex task.